# What counts as a tributary valley in Davos?

Tags: public-transport, buses, switzerland

Im looking to travel to Davos in February and will likely be making considerable use of the local public transport network. This [page](http://www.davos.ch/en/winter/mountains/tariffs-tickets/) with information about lift passes (which I will have) says "regional ski passes, issued by Davos Klosters Mountains, are full-time valid on local buses during the winter season as follows: VBD = Local bus network Davos without tributary valleys" However, I have been unable to find out exactly what counts as a "tributary valley", does anyone know how far out these regional lift passes are valid on the bus network, and specifically, if they can be used to return from the two itineraries from Jakobshorn (Muhil & Teufi).

Comment: For referance of anyone else coming accross this in future. The fare back to Davos from Teufi was 4.40CHF with a guest card. I am unware of the fare from Muhile but the guest card was not accepted. If you cross the road from the base of the slope and turn right (keep following the river) you can ski down a cross country slope to the Frauenkirch stop, from here the retun buses are more regular and covered on the gurst card. This took around 10 minuets and the slope is 95% downhill. Once you reach the railway tracks, walk across between the buildings oposite and the bus stop is on the left.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are the three valleys on [the right side of this map](http://www.vbd.ch/de/fahrplantarif/zonengrenzen/) (Flüela, Dischma, Sertig). The limit is also on the map (*Zonengrenze*). Teufi is indeed the Dischmatal and therefore would not seem to be covered by your ticket.

Comment: The link no longer points to a map.